# Nexus 7010 ACL Error

Tags: cisco, acl, cisco-nexus-7k

```
IS_NEXUS_7010(config)# interface Ethernet2/2
IS_NEXUS_7010(config-if)# description Connected to Exchange Cisco 2960 24
IS_NEXUS_7010(config-if)# switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-14
IS_NEXUS_7010(config-if)# ip access-group 110 in

ERROR: RACL policies can be configured only on Layer-3 interface which is not a port-channel member. Note that port-channel members use the ACL policies applied on port-channel interface.

IS_NEXUS_7010(config-if)#   switchport
IS_NEXUS_7010(config-if)#   switchport mode trunk
IS_NEXUS_7010(config-if)#   switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-14
```

Can't configure `ip access-group 110 in` on trunk interface Ethernet2/2, it shows the error above.  How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 8):

When you apply the ACL to a layer2 trunk, this is called a [Port ACL](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/4_1/nx-os/security/configuration/guide/sec_nx-os-cfg/sec_ipacls.html#wp1583810), use the `ip port access-group` syntax to apply it instead of `ip access-group`... explicitly...

```
IS_NEXUS_7010(config)# interface Ethernet2/2
IS_NEXUS_7010(config-if)# description Connected to Exchange Cisco 2960 24
IS_NEXUS_7010(config-if)# switchport
IS_NEXUS_7010(config-if)# switchport mode trunk
IS_NEXUS_7010(config-if)# switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-14
IS_NEXUS_7010(config-if)# ip port access-group 110 in
```